# How to Pair Item in String Array?

Tags: android, arrays, string, kotlin, key-value

I have a long string array list of "Animals" that I need to associate a code number with.
Once the "Animal" is selected via my spinner the value is stored in a variable. I also want to have the associated code number stored in its own variable.
How do I go about creating this "pairing" without writting a ton of if/then code. Can I do anything within my strings.xml file that contains my string-array?

```
        <string-array name="Animals">
          <item>Dog</item>
          <item>Cat</item>
          <item>Mouse</item>
          ...
```

"Dog" paired with code: "111"
"Cat" paired with code: '222"
"Mouse" paired with code:"333"

Comment: Your question is really unclear. It may be an XY question (https://xyproblem.info/). Can you explain more about what you’re trying to do?

Comment: @der_Fidelis Spinner says "Dog". When "Dog" is selected I want the code # associated with "Dog" for example "111" to be saved to a textView. I do not want to do a million (If"Dog" is selected then textView == "111"). Looking for a better way. Accepted answer is not really what I was looking for as it shows "(Dog, 111) in the spinner.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create the corresponding `integer-array` and `zip` them together. There is one **BIG WARNING** with this though, you have to make sure that if you change one of the arrays, you must update the other too!

Kotlin playground example:

```
fun main() {
    val stringArray: Array<String> = arrayOf("Dog", "Cat")
    val intArray: Array<String> = arrayOf("1", "0")
    print(sArray.zip(iArray))
}
```

If the corresponding code is going to be only their index in the array it's simple as:

```
arrayOf("Dog", "Cat").mapIndexed { index, animal -> index to animal }
```

So with your example it would be something like this:

```
<string-array name="Animals">
      <item>Dog</item>
      <item>Cat</item>
      <item>Mouse</item>
      ...
</string-array>

<integer-array name="AnimalsNumberCodes">
      <item>111</item>
      <item>222</item>
      <item>333</item>
      ...
</integer-array>

val listOfPairs = resources.getStringArray(R.array.Animals)
    .zip(
        resources.getIntArray(R.array.AnimalsNumberCodes).toTypedArray()
     )
```

To address the change in the question. All you have to do to get that lookup is to change to a map.

```
spinnerMap = resources.getStringArray(R.array.Animals)
    .zip(
        resources.getIntArray(R.array.AnimalsNumberCodes).toTypedArray()
     ).toMap()

spinnerMap["Dog"] // "111" or whatever you zip it with
```

Comment: Thank you for this. I am just doing the last code block part right? I am however getting an error for ".toTypedArray() it is asking to create extension function 'Array<String>.toTypedArray'. I am also getting an error dealing with my ArrayAdapter now. Any ideas?

Comment: It was my mistake when pasting the code. It was supposed to be `getIntArray`. I updated the answer.

Comment: If the code wasn't all integers how would I do it differently?

Comment: @Altohombre #1 what else could they be #2 if you are having issues with adapter. Is the question actually what you need or not?

Comment: The code could be "A12B4" or something. This is for my own reference for future use. I simplified my actual question because what I am working on is sensitive data. I made your changes and the toTypedArray error is gone. I am now having an error whee my ArrayAdapter is saying it requires a CharSequence! and not Pair<String!,Int>! I am guessing it has to do with my "private lateinit var ArrayAdapter: ArrayAdapter<CharSequence>

Comment: I think my initial question was answered the way I presented it. It is now displaying (Dog, 111) in my picker which I do not want. I want only (Dog) to appear, but have the associated code hidden to the user, but its value passed to a variable so that it can be sent to the database.

Comment: @Altohombre I updated the answer based on what you changed in the question. Send spinner only the original Animal array but when figuring out what code it is supposed to be just look it up in the map, no ifs.

Comment: what does "look it up in the map" mean? I have very little knowledge with map

Comment: As said in the answer - `spinnerMap["Dog"]` will fetch you the appropriate value. With spinner something like this `spinnerMap[spinner.getSelectedItem().toString()]`